# fetchmail mail folder

Tags: fetchmail

I configured fetchmail to fetch my mails per IMAP. After I start `fetchmail` everything is fine (see in debug-mode that mails are successfully downloaded).

The Problem is: I expect so find my mails in `$HOME/Mails`, but these folder does not exists afterwards.

I have two questions:

- Where are the mails (fetched by `fetchmail`) stored? (Ubuntu 16.04)
- How can I configure this folder?

Here is my `.fetchmailrc`:

```
set postmaster "defel"
set bouncemail
set no spambounce
set softbounce
set properties ""
set daemon 60
poll $imapserver with proto IMAP
    user 'username' there with password 'password' is 'username@imapserver.com' here ssl sslcertck
```

Comment: `username@imapserver.com` should be your local user name. The mail will be delivered to your local SMTP server. Personally I prefer to deliver to `procmail` which sorts the mail into folders.

Comment: @Kusalananda  thanks for clarifing this. Changed 'username@imapserver.com' to my local username. But `~/Mail` still does not exists.

Comment: If it's delivered to your SMTP server (`exim` or whatever you're running), I'd expect the mails to be stored in `/var/mail/username` or `/var/spool/mail/username` unless you have reconfigured it to deliver elsewhere.

Comment: Why would you think it would go to ~/Mails?

Comment: @Kusalananda These folders were also empty. @psusi I expected to get them in ~/Mails, bc afair it was so also 10 years ago, when I used fetchmail the last time. I tried now `getmail` which worked perfectly for my usecase (getting mails to $HOME)